# Passing current input value to parent compnent

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling with the search filter. Im trying to lift up my  input state to app component. Navbar component with searchbar  is rendered in App.

so:

```
        <input
        placeholder="Search..."
        type="text"
        onChange={searchHandler}
        value={inputText} />

const searchHandler = (e) => {
setInputText( e.target.value);
searchFilter(inputText) }
```

Then in App component console.log shows one char delay.
How i can handle current state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in searchHandler function, you call searchFilter before your state is set. you have two options:

1)

```
const searchHandler = (e) => {
   searchFilter(e.target.value)
}
```

2. use useEffect:

   ```
         useEffect(() => {
            searchFilter(inputText)
         }, [inputText])

         const searchHandler = (e) => {
             setInputText(e.target.value);
         }
   ```